# Using Intel TBB in debug mode

Tags: c++, tbb

I am trying to debug a C++ code using Intel Thread Building Blocks, with the procedure I have found here 
[Debugging in threading building Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887113/debugging-in-threading-building-blocks/33088351#33088351).
My question is related to the following sentence.

> Be sure to compile with the macro TBB_USE_DEBUG set to 1 so that TBB's checking will be enabled.

I have added the macro `#define TBB_USE_DEBUG 1`
at the beginning of my main function. However, when compiling I get the following warning

```
warning: "TBB_USE_DEBUG" redefined
 #define TBB_USE_DEBUG 1
/usr/include/tbb/tbb_config.h:287:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define TBB_USE_DEBUG 0
```

Hence my two questions:

- Did I put the macro at the good place ?
- How can I check that my code indeed linked with the debug library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to errortext, the define was inserted after includes. Meaning, it is very probably without any effect, because

- the define is evaluated only in previously included headers
- or because sources other than your main-function do not see the macro

To fix this

- preferred: set the define for all source-files as compiler-parameter. That is often the `-D` parameter
- or set the define before any includes in ALL sources. Often done by a delegating header.

I dont know how to test whether debug is active, as i dont know TBB.

Comment: It seems like the best solution as I have many different files. Just to give a ready for use description for potential future readers, I added `-D TBB_USE_DEBUG=1` to the compilation flags.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the `#define` *before* you include anything from the TBB library. In particular, make sure it comes before any `#include <tbb>` that may be in your source or header files.