# Thread Building Blocks segmentation fault

Tags: c++, tbb

I am trying to debug a C++ code using Intel Thread Building Blocks, following the procedure here - [Debugging in threading building Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887113/debugging-in-threading-building-blocks/33088351#33088351).

I tried running the code with one thread, and with TBB_USE_DEBUG set to 1 (I asked a previous question about it  here - [Using Intel TBB in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136667/using-intel-tbb-in-debug-mode)). However, I get a weird segmentation fault. Here is the gdb backtrace.

```
#0  0x00007ffff793fbc1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
#1  0x000000000040d2cb in tbb::task::spawn_and_wait_for_all (child=..., this=0x7ffff63b7a40)
    at /usr/include/tbb/task.h:728
#2  MpsTask1::execute (this=0x7ffff63b7a40)
    at /capps/mps_implementations.hpp:102
#3  0x00007ffff793ffdd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
#4  0x000000000040d2cb in tbb::task::spawn_and_wait_for_all (child=..., this=0x7ffff63b7d40)
    at /usr/include/tbb/task.h:728
#5  MpsTask1::execute (this=0x7ffff63b7d40)
    at /capps/mps_implementations.hpp:102
```

I am quite puzzled by this backtrace, because I cannot control what happens inside the library. Is it possible that a mistake I have made causes spawn_root_and_wait to fail ?

Here is my code (without constructor and destructor to keep it short). Its purpose is to compute the maximum prefix sum of an array via a reduction operation. It recursively divides the array until it the chunks are small enough, and then join the results. I know I could just use TBB parallel_reduce template for this problem, but my goal is to understand how TBB task based programming works.

```
class MpsTask1: public task {
public:

    task* execute(){
        if(size <= Cutoff){

            for(int i = left; i != right; i++){
                *sum = *sum + array[i]);

                if (*sum <= *mps){
                    *mps = *sum;
                    *position = i+1; 
                }
            }

            memo[depth][index] = cutoff;

        }else{
            // Parameters for subtasks
            int middle = (right+left)/2;
            int sizel = middle - left;
            int sizer = right - middle;
            int newDepth = depth + 1;
            int lIndex = 2*index;
            int rIndex = lIndex + 1;

            // Variables for results
            int lPos = left;
            int rPos = middle;
            double lsum, rsum, lmps, rmps;

            // Create subtasks
            set_ref_count(3);

            MpsTask1& lTask = *new(allocate_child()) MpsTask1(Cutoff,array,sizel,&lsum,&lmps,&lPos,memo,newDepth,lIndex,left,middle);
            spawn(lTask);

            MpsTask1 &rTask = *new(allocate_child()) MpsTask1(Cutoff,array,sizer,&rsum, &rmps,&rPos,memo,newDepth,rIndex,middle,right);

            spawn_and_wait_for_all(rTask);

            // Join results
            rmps = lsum+rmps;
            *sum = lsum+rsum;
            if(*mps <= rmps){
                *mps = rmps;
                *position = rPos;
                memo[depth][index] = rightChild;
            }
            else{
                *mps_interval = lmps;
                *position = lPos;
                memo[depth][index] = leftChild;
            }
            return NULL;
        }
    }

private:
    /* Below this size, the mps and sum are computed sequentially */
    int Cutoff;
    /* Input array and its size */
    double* array;
    int size;    
    /* Identification of the task */
    int depth;
    int index;
    int left;
    int right;
    /* Intervals for sum and mps */
    double* sum;
    double* mps;
    /* Position of the mps */
    int* position;
    // Status : left child, right child, or cutoff
    Status** memo;
};

void parallel_mps(double* array, int size, int Cutoff){
    // Create variables for result
    double sum = 0., mps = 0.;
    int position = 0;

    // Initialization of memo
    ....
    // Finished initialization of memo


    MpsTask1& root = *new(task::allocate_root()) MpsTask1(Cutoff,array,size,&sum,&mps,&position,memo);

    task::spawn_root_and_wait(root);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. It came indeed from my code. When `spawn_and_wait_for_all()` is called, it calls the `execute()` method of the previously spawned tasks, but gdb seems unable to show that in the backtrace. What worked for me is to set the number of threads to 1 and do the good old `cout << endl << "Checkpoint" << endl` debugging. 
In the present case, I forgot to return in the first if of `execute()`. Any weakness of the code seems to have dramatic consequences with TBB.